# Get time spans for customer purchases with varying gaps between purchases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and I need to figure out how to pull tracking periods for customers that have purchased products, where:

The default tracking period is 12 months after the purchase date (see Smith, Jones, Thomas).

If the customer purchases another product within that 12 months, then the tracking period is extended. So if a customer purchases an item in June of 2106, we would track through May of 2017. If that customer then purchased something else in August of 2016, I want the record to show that the tracking period was from June of 2016 (first purchase date) through August of 2017 (see Carpenter). This process should be continued for as long as the customer continues to purchase products before the end of the tracking period (see Davis).

If the customer goes 12 months without purchasing another product, and then purchases a product later, I need two records, one for each tracking period (see Henderson).

Using LEAD, I'm able to determine if a customer has a single purchase or multiple purchases, as well as the time between purchases. Here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CustomerID,
    PurchaseDate,
    ISNULL(LEAD(PurchaseDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CustomerID, PurchaseDate), DATEADD(MONTH, 12, PurchaseDate)) TrackThroughDate,
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, PurchaseDate, ISNULL(LEAD(PurchaseDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CustomerID, PurchaseDate), DATEADD(MONTH, 12, PurchaseDate))) AS NumberOfMonths
FROM 
    PurchaseDetail
WHERE 
    PurchaseDate > '2014/06/30'
ORDER BY 
    CustomerID, PurchaseDate
```

And some sample data from this is (the number of months is not necessary, I'm only including it to make the conditions above a little easier to identify in the results):

[image]

So what I need is this:

[image]

Any suggestions on a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign tracking periods using `lag()`, running sums, and some lock:

```
select pd.customerid,
       sum(case when prev_purchasedate > dateadd(year, -1, purchasedate)
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (partition by customerid order by purchasedate) as trackingperiod
from (select pd.*,
             lag(purchasedate) over (partition by customerid order by purchasedate) as prev_purchasedate
      from purchasedetail pd
     ) pd;
```

This defines the beginning of the tracking period based on the purchase dates.  A cumulative sum of the beginnings then defines the tracking periods themselves.

If you want to summarize these, the logic simply adds one year to the maximum date in the period:

```
select customerid, min(purchasedate) as purchasedate,
       dateadd(year, 1, max(purchasedate)) as trackthroughdate
from (select pd.*,
             sum(case when prev_purchasedate > dateadd(year, -1, purchasedate)
                      then 0 else 1
                 end) over (partition by customerid order by purchasedate) as trackingperiod
      from (select pd.*,
                   lag(purchasedate) over (partition by customerid order by purchasedate) as prev_purchasedate
            from purchasedetail pd
           ) pd
     ) pd
group by customerid, trackingperiod;
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks very much. This worked, although I had to tweak the syntax a bit - I had to add pd.purchasedate between pd.customerId and sum(case when...) in lines 3 and 4.  Other than that, though, this was great, and a very clever "twist" on the running total recipe using window functions.  Thanks again.